# running queries using bash script

Tags: neo4j

I need to run Neo4j on Kali linux, use a bash script to start it and run my intended Cypher queries. Is it possible? If so, would you please tell me how can I do this? I didn't find anything about this. All I have done is this:

```
sudo apt-get install neo4j
```

which has installed neo4j on my Kali. What should I do next?

To further clarify my question: I have a bash script which produces a .csv file. Now I want to use this .csv file to create a graph in neo4j. I want to know whether there is any way that after creating the .csv file in my bash script to run the neo4j through the same bash script and create the graph through the query I have written for .csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j includes [cypher-shell](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/), a command line tool that you can use to connect to Neo4j and execute queries.

Rather than invoking this in an interactive way, you can execute cypher directly when issuing the command to run cypher-shell, and you can also pipe in a file with cypher commands to execute, and also supply parameters to use when executing the cypher. Provided that the CSV file is in an accessible location (should be in the import folder under your neo4j home folder), you can supply the parameter of the file name, and use that parameter in the cypher query provided when executing cypher-shell.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem really lost, a good start is always to have a look at the [doc](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/). Everything you could possibly wonder is explainer there. Try to search the internet a bit when something seems wrong.

> "Cypher is a declarative query language for graphs. For more details, see the Cypher Manual. The recommended way of programmatically interacting with the database is either through the official drivers or using the Java API." (From the doc, Introduction

Apparently, you don't even need to use bash which is old school and not very handy to use unless you already know very well what you are doing. You can use the Java API instead if you know this language.

[Here](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/4.0/get-started/#driver-get-started-installation) you will even find how to use drivers to use it with the popular JavaScript!

You should precise your question.

Comment: I have a bash script which produces a .csv file. Now I want to use this .csv file to create a graph in neo4j. I want to know whether there is any bash command that is able to run the neo4j after creating the .csv file and create the graph through the query I have written for it.